# How to count the unique values in 2 fields without concatenating them?

Tags: linux, field, uniq

I am trying to using the basic shell in unix to count the unique values in 2 fields. I have data with 5 columns but just what to count the unique values in the first 2 WITHOUT concatenating them.
So far I am successful in using cut -f 1 | sort | uniq | wc -l in counting the unique values in column one and I can do the same for column two but because some of the values are the same in column one and two I need to be able to do this command treating column 1 and 2 as one field. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't fully understand: does the *combination* of column 1 and column 2 have to be unique?

Comment: It might help to provide an example of your data.

Comment: Does 
" cut -f 1,2 | sort | uniq | wc -l " not give your desired results

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be interpreted in two ways so I answer both of them.

Given the input file:

```
2       1
2       1
1       2
1       1
2       2
```

If you want the result to output **4** because the unique pairs are `1 1`, `1 2`, `2 1` and `2 2`, then you need:

```
cat test|cut -f1,2|sort|uniq|wc -l
```

What we do here: we pick only first two columns as well as the delimiter and pass it to `sort|uniq` which does the job.

If you, on the other hand, want the result to output **2** because there are only two unique elements: `1` and `2`, then you can tweak the above like this:

```
cat test|cut -f1,2|tr "\t" "\n"|sort|uniq|wc -l
```

This time after we select first two columns, we split each of them into two lines so that `sort|uniq` picks them up.

These work as long as the columns are separated with TAB character, not spaces. Since you didn't pass `-d` option to `cut` in your question and `cut` uses tabs by default, I assumed your input uses tabs too.

Comment: would there be a way to adjust this so you would get an output of 3 because there are 3 unique combinations of values (2 2, 1 1, and 1 2)?